# "Apache2 restart failed "nextcloud instance

Tags: openssl, apache2, nextcloud

on running command

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Recieved this output

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details

"systemctl status apache2.service" returned this output
`apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-02-01 00:52:42 UTC; 2min 16s ago Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ Process: 85168 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) CPU: 34ms`

"journalctl -xeu apache2.service" did not output anything.

A little back story. I have a nextcloud instance set up on linode. I went to look at nextcloud on my android and it was saying "ssl initiation error". On pulling up my domain on browser I found the base apache2 webdrop that you get before apache2 is setup. I check out some configurations to no avail. I basically re-follow online tutorial i used to set up server and I get to restarting apache2 and the situation above takes place.
any thoughts or direction will help
thank you

Comment: What happens if you start the httpd itself directly via CLI? Instead of using the service control system?

Comment: What does the http server's error log file contain?